# Receiving a NoClassDefFoundError (Eclipse generated jar) using Apache procrun but runs fine on command line

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, procrun

I have exported my application as one large package from Eclipse so it uses the Eclipse loader.  I have installed it with procrun using an install.bat file, the most important lines are shown below:

```
set PR_CLASSPATH=C:\somepath\ECGIServer.jar
set PR_LIBRARYPATH=C:\somepath\native\lunaLibrary.dll
set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STOPMODE=jvm
```

Obviously there is much more and the service does run. In the ECGIServer.jar file, here is the Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ commons-codec-1.6.jar stax-api-1.0-2.jar LunaProvider.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: ecgi.encrypter.ECgiServer
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

There are more jar's to list but too many to write. Regardless, when I run it (ECGIServer.jar) at the command line it works great. When I run it as a service, it runs until I try to create an instance of LunaProvider. Once the application creates an instance of LunaProvider I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/safenetinc/luna/provider/LunaProvider
```

As you can see, LunaProvider is a ThridParty library that's just being pulled in from my Eclipse setup.

Comment: is that lib really inside your jar?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I opened the LunaProvider.jar within the ECGIServer.jar and the class IS there and it's at the correct path. I just added another line to the install.bat, PR_LIBRARYPATH, it requires a .dll dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally decided to try exporting dependent directories from Eclipse to a separate directory.  After I did this all my dependencies, including LunaProvider.jar got dumped into that directory.  I changed the following line in the install.bat file to:

```
set PR_CLASSPATH=C:\somepath\ECGIServer.jar;C:\somepath\ECGIServer_lib
```

And everything worked out just fine.  Still can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured it out to make it work, was generating jar and the library folder apart. This generates .jar file and a directory called YourAppName_lib.
So in the .bat you have to set PR_LIBRARYPATH to the _lib folder and that´s it.